# how to specify persistent hard drive for disk widgets of awesome wm?

Tags: widget, hard-drive, awesome-wm

I am using dio and hddtemp widgets (`Vicious`) to display IO rate and hard drive temperature. The problem is that I have to change the input device name every time I reboot the computer, because the order in which the devices are added during booting is arbitrary. This results in device names like /dev/sda and /dev/sdb switching around on each boot for the same hard drive. This is usually solved by using UUID in other scenarios. I am wondering, is there solution to this problem for aswsome vicious widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` for this. Something like the following could work:

```
handle = io.popen("readlink /dev/disk/by-uuid/abc-def-geh")
disk = handle:read("*all"):match("sd[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
handle:close()
```

This should give you the name of the device in the variable `disk`.

Comment: this is a nice solution!